# Vertical lines in matrices should be aligned

Tags: math-mode, matrices, arrays

I'm trying to write matrices one below the other but I want the vertical lines (compare example below) to be aligned. Eventually, there will be several matrices in one document - in the example below there are only two.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{I} \\
\mathrm{II} \\
\mathrm{III} \\
\end{array}
\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
3 & 6 & 3 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right )
\begin{array}{c}
\\
\mathrm{II} + \left (-\frac 2 3 \right ) \cdot \mathrm{I} \\
\mathrm{III} + \left (\frac 1 3 \right ) \cdot \mathrm{I}\\
\end{array}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{I^{**}}\\
\mathrm{II^{**}} \\
\mathrm{III^{***}} \\
\end{array}
\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right )
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the numbers in the last column are of the same size, you can just put both matrices in the same `align` and put the alignment point (`&`) just after the matrices. I also added some extra space between the two lines with `\\[2\jot]`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{I} \\
\mathrm{II} \\
\mathrm{III} 
\end{array}
\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
3 & 6 & 3 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & 2 & 1 
\end{array}
\right )&
\begin{array}{c}
\\
\mathrm{II} + \left (-\frac 2 3 \right ) \cdot \mathrm{I} \\
\mathrm{III} + \left (\frac 1 3 \right ) \cdot \mathrm{I}
\end{array}
\\[2\jot]
\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{I^{**}}\\
\mathrm{II^{**}} \\
\mathrm{III^{***}} 
\end{array}
\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 
\end{array}
\right )&
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

In order to further ease the reader's ability to let his/her eye roam vertically across the display, I would not only align the two vertical bars but also the various columns of the matrices through judicious insertions of `\phantom{-}` instructions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{I} \\
\mathrm{II} \\
\mathrm{III\phantom{^{***}}} \\
\end{array}
&\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
3 & \phantom{-}6 & 3 & 3 \\
2 & 1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right )
\begin{array}{l}
\\
\mathrm{II} + \left (-\tfrac 2 3 \right ) \cdot \mathrm{I} \\
\mathrm{III} + \left (\tfrac 1 3 \right ) \cdot \mathrm{I}\\
\end{array}
\\
\begin{array}{l}
\mathrm{I^{**}}\\
\mathrm{II^{**}} \\
\mathrm{III^{***}} \\
\end{array}
&\left (
\begin{array}{rrr|r}
\phantom{-}1 & \phantom{-}0 & \phantom{-}0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right )
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{vlines-in-sub-matrix=I}

\[\begin{NiceArray}{lcccIcl}
\mathrm{I}         & 3  & 6 & 3  & 3  \\
\mathrm{II}        & 2  & 1 & -1 & -1 & \mathrm{II}+\bigl(-\frac{2}{3}\bigr)\cdot \mathrm{I} \\
\mathrm{III}       & -1 & 2 & 2  & 1  & \mathrm{III} + \bigl(\frac{1}{3}\bigr) \cdot \mathrm{I} \\[2mm]
\mathrm{I^{**}}    & 1  & 0 & 0  & 1  \\
\mathrm{II^{**}}   & 0  & 1 & 0  & -1 \\
\mathrm{III^{***}} & 0  & 0 & 1  & 2  \\
\CodeAfter
   \SubMatrix({1-2}{3-5})
   \SubMatrix({4-2}{6-5})
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]